# Get values of Macro Variables in a SAS Table

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide, sas-stored-process

I have a set of input macro variables in SAS. They are dynamic and generated based on the user selection in a sas stored process.

```
For example:There are 10 input values 1 to 10.
The name of the macro variable is VAR_. If a user selects 2,5,7 then 4 macro variables are created. 
&VAR_0=3;
&VAR_=2;
&VAR_1=5;
&VAR_2=7;
```

The first one with suffix 0 provides the count. The next 3 provides the values.

Note:If a user select only one value then only one macro variable is created. For example If a user selects 9 then &var_=9; will be created. There will not be any count macro variable. 
I am trying to create a sas table using these variables.

It should be like this

```
OBS    VAR
-----------
1      2
2      5
3      7
-----------
```

This is what I tried. Not sure if this is the right way to do approach it.
It doesn't give me a final solution but I can atleast get the name of the macro variables in a table. How can I get their values ?

```
data tbl1;
do I=1 to &var_0;
VAR=CAT('&VAR_',I-1);
OUTPUT;
END;
RUN;
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TBL2 AS 
SELECT I,
CASE WHEN VAR= '&VAR_0' THEN '&VAR_' ELSE VAR END AS VAR
from TBL1;
QUIT;
```

Thank You for your help.

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your numbering scheme and recommend changing it, if you can; the `&var_` variable is very confusing.

Anyway, the easiest way to do this is [`SYMGET`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202938.htm).  That returns a value from the macro symbol table which you can specify at runtime.

```
%let VAR_0=3;
%let VAR_=2;
%let VAR_1=5;
%let VAR_2=7;

data want;  
  do obs = 1 to &var_0.;
    var = input(symget(cats('VAR_',ifc(obs=1,'',put(obs-1,2.)))),2.);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: The variable pattern looks like how the web interface from SAS returns user selections.  I have also seen where it just returns the one variable and does not create the `_0` variable at all.

Comment: @Tom Hmm, that's very odd then.  Why would the 'first' be `&var_` and not `&var_1`??

Comment: Not sure, I assumed the logic went like this. If you define the field as MONTH and it is not multi-select then get a variable named MONTH. So they wanted to also return a variable name MONTH when it is multi-select. I haven't looked at it in years, but I thought that it made both the MONTH and MONTH1.  But perhaps it was my code that added the MONTH1 since it seemed so strange.

Comment: Thank You Joe. Worked fine. Appreciate your help. Tom is correct. The naming convention is a little different. The first variable will be under both VAR_ and VAR_1. If there is only one value selected then there will be only one variable i.e. VAR_.

Comment: If that's the case (if VAR_1 = VAR) then you won't need the I-1 bit or the IFC bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real issue is the inconsistent behavior of the stored process. It only creates the `0` and `1` variable when there are multiple selections.  I think that your example is a little off. If the value of `VAR_0` is three then their should be a `VAR_3` macro variable. Also the value of `VAR_` and `VAR_1` should be set to the same thing.

To fix this in the past I have done something like this.  First let's assign the parameter name a macro variable so that the code is reusable for other programs.

```
%let name=VAR_;
```

Then first make sure the minimal macro variables exist.

```
%global &name &name.0 &name.1 ;
```

Then make sure that you have a count by setting the `0` variable to 1 when it is empty.

```
%let &name.0 = %scan(&&&name.0 1,1);
```

Then make sure that you have a `1` variable.  Since it should have the same value as the macro variable without a suffix just re-assign it.

```
%let &name.1 = &&&name ;
```

Now your data step is easier.

```
data want ;
  length var $32 value $200 ;
  do i=1 to &&&name.0 ;
    var=cats(symget('name'),i);
    value=symget(var);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

SAS helpfully stores them in a table for you already, you just need to parse out the ones you want. The table is called SASHELP.VMACRO or DICTIONARY.MACROS

Here's an example:

```
%let var=1;
%let var2=3;
%let var4=5;

proc sql;
create table want as
select * from sashelp.vmacro
where name like 'VAR%';
quit;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: Thank You Reeza. Worked fine. Appreciate your help.